# Получение оптимальной кодировки

Tags: c#

Я хочу сохранить строку юзера(которую он введёт) в текстовый файл, но при этом использовать оптимальную кодировку. То есть сделать enum из кодировок, а потом в файл первым байтом записывать index enum'а, а далее уже саму строку в оптимальном кодировке, чтобы файл занимал минимальное количество байт

Comment: Вы потом больше нервов потратите на то, чтобы прочитать этот файл (если нужно будет), не говоря уж о том, что юзер откроет его через блокнот и увидит там закорючки потому что блокнот не будет поддерживать какую-то там кодировку которая на полтора байта меньше займет памяти, юзайте UTF-8 и не усложняйте жизнь себе в первую очередь

Comment: Отставим в сторону бредовость затеи, рассмотрим способ её реализации. Имеем строку. Проходим в цикле по всем кодировкам, получаем массив байтов из этой строки. Выбираем самый короткий массив. Ничего сложного.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, При сохранении строки в несоответствующую кодировку будет потеряно много информации. Символы из другой кодировки просто сохранятся в виде '?'

Comment: Если цель сэкономить место, то не проще ли упаковывать текст каким-нибудь стандартным методом архивации, вроде для `C#` был какой-то стандартный `Zip` доступен библиотечный, ну или там `Gzip`. Раньше мы так реально делали, в том числе когда в БД большие тексты сохраняли. Сложностей с чтением чем-то другим такого файла будет даже меньше, если делать нормальный файл архива с правильным расширением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перебираем все имеющиеся кодировки.
Получаем массив байт из строки.
Проверяем, что обратное преобразование выполняется корректно.
Выбираем минимальный размер массива.

```
string s = "こんにちは";

// Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

var x = Encoding.GetEncodings()
    .Select(info => info.GetEncoding())
    .Select(enc => new { Encoding = enc, Bytes = enc.GetBytes(s) })
    .Where(x => x.Encoding.GetString(x.Bytes) == s)
    .MinBy(x => x.Bytes.Length);

Console.WriteLine(x.Encoding);
```

Теперь как-то сохраняем строку в файл.
`x.Bytes` уже содержит массив байтов в нужной кодировке. Можно использовать их напрямую.

По умолчанию в последних версиях дотнета подключено мало кодировок (только основные). Если нужны все, то раскомментируйте `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);`

Следует учитывать, что на разных компьютерах могут быть установлены разные кодировки. Поэтому не следует использовать редкие.

PS: Не забываем про [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)!